# UICollectionViewCell loaded from Xib (Nib) is being covered by storyboard cells as its size is not updating

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a `Xib` file to hold a `UICollectionViewCell` item that I do not want to have in a `Storyboard`. I have the `UICollectionView` set to calculate its cell sizes automatically. But what I see when the collection view loads is that it's retaining the default 50x50 size for the cell that's being loaded from the `Xib` file. It's not being updated to the size it is showing up as.

The cell looks correct on screen and at the correct size. But when another cell loads that is contained in the storyboard it's loading on top of the other cell as its being placed 50 points down from the first cell.

[image: Showing the cell being which I've outlined in orange covered by one outlined in green]

The cell outlined in orange is the one being covered up by the one in green. I cannot show a larger portion of this due to work restrictions but I hope this clarifies what's happening.

I've tried to say that the `cellNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` but neither of those make any difference. It's like the actual height that the cell is not being calculated early enough to have the collection view place cells around it correctly.

I've not been able to find a way to preload the `Xib` so that it already knows how large that needs to be. I am using a subclass of UICollectionView named CollectionCell.

Can anyone point me in the direction to look or suggest a fix for this other than moving what I've done into the `Storyboard`?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113202/how-can-i-calculate-the-size-of-a-uicollectionviewcell-loaded-from-a-xib-with-au?rq=1 ... if not, I'd suggest creating a new project with *minimal* code, and see if you can reproduce the problem. Very tough to help if you can't (not allowed to) show exactly what you're doing.

Comment: try collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

Comment: try to provide some code, otherwise we will be throwing stones blindly.